# Sk-learn LDA for topic extraction, perplexity and score

Tags: scikit-learn, text-classification, lda, supervised-learning, perplexity

Hello all!

As apart of a project, I need to build a text classifier with the labeled data I have. A data point is composed of a single sentences and one of 3 categories for each sentence. I have extracted 5 topics from this database with LDA.

What I want to try is that I want to use these topics to determine which class an unseen sentence belongs to. I am thinking about training a supervised model with 5 indicator that show the topic distribution for a sentence given those 5 topics.

The problem is that I can not get separate likelihood for each topic given a sentence. I am confused about what perplexity and score of a LDA model indicates. They seem to return single float value.

Also, I am aware of supervised versions of LDA. I want to know if my approach make sense at all.

Thanks in advance!